# Is there an API to send calls to voicemail in Android?

Tags: android

I was looking for an API to send incoming calls to voicemail.

I know this can be done using the Contact app that comes with any Android 
phones. But is there an API for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html) to see when a call is coming in, but there's no way to connect and control phone calls themselves. Placing a phone call is a core and critical feature of a phone.  I'm very sure this reason alone warrants no API for direct manipulation of phone calls.

Comment: Actually using iTelephony interface with an aidl file you can - I just wrote an app to do this.  It just requires peeking a bit deeper into the Android OS itself rather than relying on a public API.  On newer devices I understand that the dialer app is replacing the telephony interface, I don't know how that will affect this answer.

Answer (score 2):

ContactsContract.RawContacts
has got a flag to indicate that call should be forwarded to voice mail

SEND_TO_VOICEMAIL read/write An indicator of whether calls from this raw contact should be forwarded directly to voice mail ('1') or not ('0'). To have an effect on the corresponding value of the aggregate contact, this field should be set at the time the raw contact is inserted.

Comment: How can I implement it?

Comment: Downvoted - Really should have some measure of implementation.